# Git Merge some folder

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I have two git local branches named A and B (which points to the remote branches origin/A and origin/B.

```
Branch - A:

Folder-1
   File-11
   File-12
Folder-2
   File-21
   File-22

Branch - B:
Folder-2
   File-22
   File-23
Folder-3
   File-31
   File-32
```

I want to merge branch B with branch A.

```
git checkout A
git merge B
```

The final out come should be like this.

```
Branch - A:
Folder-1
   File-11
   File-12
Folder-2
   File-21
   File-22 (Branch -A file).
Folder-3
   File-31
   File-32
```

Merge Folder-3 alone, keep Folder-1 and Folder-2 from branch A.

The basic requirement is, I should not loss logs (and commits) history.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing the merge and then rearranging the folders the way you want them (after resolving merge conflicts, of course) ?  I'm not sure I understand why you are even asking a question.

Comment: You can create a `branch C` out of `branch B` delete `Folder-1` and `Folder-2` and then `merge` `branch C` into `branch A`

Comment: how to create local branch C? I don't want the branch C to be pushed to remote git repo, what do I need to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: After merge I will get merge conflict for Folder-2/File-22 and Folder-2/File-23 will be added. I don't want both to be happen.

Comment: Then resolve the conflicts and deal with it.  This is the way to go I believe.

Comment: I just want to overwrite the file with whatever there in branch A. Its around 1000 files inside a folder. how to do that?

Comment: @Surendhar No it wont get pushed to remote unless you manually push it. I will post answer.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to mark  the commit as a merge commit, here is one way to do this :

```
# from branch A :
git checkout A

# say "start a merge commit, I initially want to only keep the content of A" :
git merge -s ours --no-commit B
  # -s ours : keep current branch content (current branch is A)
  # --no-commit : do not run the 'git commit' command yet, I will do it later

# say "get me the content of Folder-3 from branch B" :
git checkout B -- Folder-3/

# and commit this new content on top of branch A :
git commit
```

With this option : branch `B` will be marked as merged into `A`, and you will see the history of commits :

```
$ git log --oneline --graph A
* aa1234 (HEAD -> A) Merged branch 'B' into A
|\
| * bb1234 (B) update 3 on branch B
| * cc1234 update 2 on branch B
| * dd1234 update 1 on branch B
...
```

---

If you just want to add the content of `Folder-3` from branch `B` to branch `A`, and do not care about making this commit a merge commit, here is a simpler way to do this :

```
# from branch A :
git checkout A

# say "get me the content of Folder-3 from branch B" :
git checkout B -- Folder-3/

# and commit this new content on top of branch A :
git commit
```

Comment: is this "git checkout B -- Folder-3/" also copy the logs and commit history?

Comment: @Surendhar : it's the `git merge` that does this. You need the second version then.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$ git checkout branchB
$ git checkout -b branchC
$ rm -rf folderA and folderB //pseudocode. Remove folder A and B
$ git checkout branchA
$ git merge branchC
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Added folderC"
$ git push

$ git branch -d branchC
```

Comment: After "rm -rf folderA and folderB" Do I need to commit or do anything else to reflect the changes in branchC?

Comment: Yeah if you want. Do `git add -A` and `git commit` just to be on safe side, then merge branchC into branchA.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout B
git add Folder-3
git add Folder-2/File-23
git checkout -- Folder-2/File-22
git comit -m "add Folder-3"
git checkout A
git merge B
```

Comment: What does git checkout -- will do?

Comment: git checkout -- filename cancel edit in this file to take origin copy